# Calculating child div top position - why does parent offsetHeight need to be subtracted?

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a magnifier in pure js. What I discovered in needing to translate the mouse position of a div relative to its parents is that in calculating the top for the overlaying magnifier div, the offsetTop works differently than the offsetLeft. After adjusting for what ***should be*** the top, I need to subtract the whole container div's offsetHeight.

The line in the code in question is this:

```
magnifier.style.top = yPosition - container.offsetHeight + "px";
```

Why do I need to subtract `container.offsetHeight`?

I know I've read something regarding this, but can't find it.

**Disclaimers** This code is working. I am asking so I (and those following) can understand how the box model works.

I know there are jQuery alternatives that are more cross browser reliable. I like to code it myself so that I can learn how it all works. If you see something which is not compatible for a modern browser, feel free to comment.

Lastly, For anyone using this, I removed code from this example to adjust for transforms. For example, if the wrapper has a `transform: translate(-50%, 0);` to center the wrapper horizontally, you will need to add the resulting amount of the translation (which translates to the wrapper's left position) back into the calculation.

I have created a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/3w26fcx0/). I left more comments in the Fiddle as to methodology if anyone is interested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../css/ms.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
/********************/
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}

#container {
    width: 527px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#image {
    width: 527px;
    height: 450px;
}

#magnifier {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;   
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: solid 1px;
}

#magnifier img {
    position: absolute;    
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="../docs/grade-2/jpg/g2-bb-saints-francis.jpg">
    <div id="magnifier" class="magnifier">
        <img id="imagecopy">        
    </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Zoom" onClick="initmagnifier('magnifier', 'image', 'imagecopy');"><br>
</div>


<script>

function initmagnifier(magnifier, image, imagecopy){
    var magnifier = document.getElementById("magnifier");
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var img = document.getElementById(image);
    var imgcopy = document.getElementById(imagecopy);
    var zoom = 2;
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", 
    function(e){
        movemagnifier(e, img, imgcopy, magnifier, container, wrapper, zoom)
    }, false);
    var src = img.src;
    imgcopy.src = src;
    var src2 = imgcopy.src;

    imgcopy.height = img.height * zoom;
    imgcopy.width = img.width * zoom ;
}

 function movemagnifier(e, img, imgcopy, magnifier, container, wrapper, zoom) {
    // to get the left & top of the magnifier    
    // position needs to be adjusted for WRAPPER & CONTAINER top and left    
    // gets the top and left of the container
    var containerPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);

    // adjust out the CONTAINER's top / left
    // Then takes 1/2 the hight of the MAGNIFIER and subtracts it from the MOUSE position to center MAGNIFIER around the MOUSE cursor
    var xPosition = e.clientX - containerPosition.x - (magnifier.clientWidth / 2);
    var yPosition = e.clientY - containerPosition.y - (magnifier.clientHeight / 2);

    magnifier.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    magnifier.style.top = yPosition - container.offsetHeight + "px";

    // Adjust for zoom
    // adjust the MAGNIFIER's top/left at an equal pace to the zoom amount
    var yTravel = (e.clientY - containerPosition.y ) * (zoom - 1);
    var yimgPosition = -(yPosition - container.clientTop + yTravel);
    imgcopy.style.top = yimgPosition  + "px";

    var xTravel = (e.clientX - containerPosition.x) * (zoom - 1);   // * 1.5
    var ximgPosition = -(xPosition + xTravel);
    imgcopy.style.left = ximgPosition + "px";

console.log('****');
console.log(e.clientY); // MOUSE POSTION
console.log(containerPosition.y);
console.log(wrapper.offsetTop);
console.log(wrapper.clientHeight);

console.log(container.offsetTop);
console.log(container.clientHeight);
console.log(yPosition);
console.log(container.offsetHeight);
console.log(magnifier.style.top);
}

function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;
    // element is the CONTAINER
    // This calculates the postion of the element (CONTAINER) TOP & LEFT relative to ALL parents
    while (element) {
    // if transform: translate in place for x and y,
    // add it back as it skews the offsetLeft offsetTop values by the translate amount
        xPosition += ((element.offsetLeft) - element.scrollLeft);
        yPosition += ((element.offsetTop) - element.scrollTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me longer than I care to admit, but I have found the reason. In your fiddle you position the `#magnifier`-element relative, which means you have to move it from its 'natural' position, which is below the image inside the container.

So with every move you have to compensate for this, by pulling the `#magnifier` to the top/left position of the container, the left position already matches, but the 'natural' top position of the `#magnifier` is the full height of the container, as you calculate from the top/left position of the `#container`, you need to subtract the `#container` height.

A simple fix is to add `position: relative` to the `#container` and change `position: relative` on the `#magnifier` to `position: absolute`.

This will give you the expected coordinate system for the `#magnifier` as `top: 0; left: 0` for the absolute positioned element is the top left corner of the its relative parent (the first positioned parent element, in this case `#container`).

[a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/3w26fcx0/8/) without the need to to subtract `container.offsetHeight`.

---

While I'm at it, you may want to look into the [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) function, as you can get all information you need to determine the position in a single call.

Comment: I know what you mean about "longer than I care to admit." I have spent way too many hours on this... and other SO answers of my own. Thanks for the time it took - it is really appreciated. I obviously didn't know about getBoundingClientRect - it looks very useful. Have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help ;-) One note about the `getBoundingClientRect`, it will trigger a [redraw](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/), so you may want to cache its output and/or use it in a ['requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)